# Access part of a javascript array (mysqljs)

Tags: javascript, mysql, mysqljs

I am pulling data from a database in javascript using mysqljs

I can get the output:

```
{ 
  "Success": true,
  "Result": [{ 
    "buttonName": "90p"
  }, {
    "buttonName": "£1.90"
  }, {
    "buttonName": "£4.90"
  }]
}
```

Using:

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
```

However, how do I access each part of the array.

I have tried:

```
data[1].buttonName
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over that array `Result`.

**For example:** `data.Result[index].buttonName`

This example loops that array and appends new elements to the `div` with id `output`.

```js
var data = { 
  "Success": true,
  "Result": [{ 
    "buttonName": "90p"
  }, {
    "buttonName": "£1.90"
  }, {
    "buttonName": "£4.90"
  }]
}

var output = document.getElementById("output");
data.Result.forEach(function(o) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(o.buttonName));
  output.appendChild(p);
});
```

```html
<div id='output'>
</div>
```